# Create if record does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models in my rails app

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey, counter_cache: :contact_count
  belongs_to :voter
  has_many :contact_attempts
end

class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :contacts
end

class Voter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
end
```

the Contact consists of the voter_id and a survey_id. The Logic of my app is that a there can only be one  contact for a voter in any given survey.

right now I am using the following code to enforce this logic. I query the contacts table for records matching the given voter_id and survey_id. if does not exist then it is created. otherwise it does nothing.

```
if !Contact.exists?(:survey_id => survey, :voter_id => voter)
   c = Contact.new
   c.survey_id = survey
   c.voter_id = voter
   c.save
end
```

Obviously this requires a select and a insert query to create 1 potential contact. When I am adding potentially thousands of contacts at once.

Right now I'm using Resque to allow this run in the background and away from the ui thread. What can I do to speed this up, and make it  more efficient?

Comment: If you're adding thousands at once why not do it with a bulk insert or some other mechanism outside of AR?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should add first a database index to force this condition at the lowest level as possible:

```
add_index :contacts, [:voter_id, :survey_id], unique: true
```

Then you should add an uniqueness validation at an ActiveRecord level:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :voter_id, scope: [:survey_id]
```

Then `contact.save` will return `false` if a contact exists for a specified voter and survey.

UPDATE: If you create the index, then the uniqueness validation will run pretty fast.

Answer (score 53):

You can do the following:

```
Contact.where(survey_id: survey,voter_id: voter).first_or_create
```

Answer (score 20):

See if those links can help you.

Those links are for rails 4.0.2, but you can change in the api docks

From the apidock: [first_or_create](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create), [find_or_create_by](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by) 
From the Rails Guide: [find-or-create-by](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-create-by)

Answer (score 4):

It would be better if you let MySQL to handle it.

Create a migration and add a **composite unique key** to `survey_id, voter_id`

```
add_index :contact, [:survey_id, :voter_id], :unique=> true
```

Now

```
Contact.create(:survey_id=>survey, :voter_id=>voter_id)
```

Will create new record only if there is no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find_or_create_by` method for this. You can optionally pass a block to this method if you want to check for certain fields only. This block will only be executed if no record is found.

[The docs say](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1.3.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by):

> The block will only be executed if the customer is being created. The second time we run this code, the block will be ignored.

It works like:

```
Contact.find_or_create_by({survey_id: survey,voter_id: voter})
```

Or with the block like:

```
Contact.find_or_create_by({survey_id: survey}) do |contact|
    contact.voter_id = voter
end
```